# How do I change the direction of a vertical Waffle?

Tags: python, matplotlib, waffle-chart

I have this script that generates a Waffle of example date:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pywaffle import Waffle
values = [3, 8, 9, 13, 9, 4, 5, 9, 10, 7, 4, 1]
colors = ["#1D428A", "#5566A6", "#838DC2", "#B1B6DF", "#DEE1FC", "#FFFFFF"]
colors = colors + colors[::-1]
fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass = Waffle,
    columns = 4,
    values = values[::-1],
    colors = colors,
    block_arranging_style = "snake",
    vertical = True)
plt.savefig("test1.png")
```

The result looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTuGW.jpg.
In short, I want the direction of the Waffle to be changed: instead of two squares in the first line and four in the last one, I want the opposite: four squares in the first line and two in the last one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using it for the first time, but I think it is possible with the direction setting in the [official reference](https://pywaffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/block_shape_spacing_location_direction_and_style.html).

> Where to Start First Block Use parameter starting_location to set the
> location of starting block. It accepts locations in string like NW,
> SW, NE and SE representing four corners. By default, it is SW, meaning
> PyWaffle starts drawing blocks from lower-left corner.
>
> Here is an example that start plotting from lower-right corner (SE).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pywaffle import Waffle
values = [3, 8, 9, 13, 9, 4, 5, 9, 10, 7, 4, 1]
colors = ["#1D428A", "#5566A6", "#838DC2", "#B1B6DF", "#DEE1FC", "#FFFFFF"]
colors = colors + colors[::-1]
fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass = Waffle,
    columns=4,
    values = values[::-1],
    colors = colors,
    block_arranging_style = "snake",
    vertical = True,
    starting_location='NE'
    )
plt.savefig("test1.png")
```

[image]